# Dojo ItemFileWriteStore issue with IE7

Tags: internet-explorer-7, dojo, grid

I have a grid that is embedded within a ContentPane which is in a tabContainer. When loading the itemfilewritestore IE7 pops an error.

Code:

var theData = {identifies : id , items[]};
var theStore = new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore({data: theData});

console.debug(theStore); // this throws some weird error

error:
{close:function(_81)if(!this.isDirty)........There are unsaved changes present in the store Please save or revert the changes before invoking close.

This error only shows itself in IE7. FF has no problem and renders the data properly. And yes I know there is no data in this code but in the real code the data is added later.

Comment: console.debug isn't consistent across all the browsers. Are you sure the console.debug call isn't what's causing the problem?  Also, try running Dojo from source without a 'build' so that variable names like _81 will come through uncompressed.  In Firebug or Visual Studio you should actually be able to get a stack trace for exceptions, or put in breakpoints/debugger statements to see what's going on.

Comment: I am pretty sure the debug.console command is not the issue. The error is also evident in the fact that the grid itself does not show the data that is within the store. I put the console.debug  command to track the error. The error being supplied, after getting the source:

Comment: {close:function(/* object? */ request) 
 { // summary: 
   // Over-ride of base close function of ItemFileReadStore to add in check for store state. 
   // description: 
   // Over-ride of base close function of ItemFileReadStore to add in check for store state. 
   // If the store is still dirty (unsaved changes), then an error will be thrown instead of 
   // clearing the internal state for reload from the url. 
   //Clear if not dirty ... or throw an error

Comment: if(this.clearOnClose){ 
  if(!this.isDirty()){ 
   this.inherited(arguments); 
  }else if(this._jsonFileUrl !== ""){ 
   //Only throw an error if the store was dirty and we were loading from a url (cannot reload from url until state is saved). 
   throw new Error("dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore: There are unsaved changes present in the store. 
    Please save or revert the changes before invoking close."); 
  } 
 }

Comment: } onDelete:function(
 /* item */ deletedItem){ 
  // summary: See dojo.data.api.Notification.onDelete() 
  // No need to do anything. This method is here just so that the 
  // client code can connect observers to it. 
  } 
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was not as described. The error was not the store in any way. After digging around more, I found out that the real problem was a parsing on a javascript that was being imported. Going step by step through it the problem was because a JSON object was using the term "class" as an attribute. This seems to be against the IE "standards".

Comment: "class", "default" and a number of other reserved JavaScript words will do this. Glad you caught it. JSON states all keys should be quoted. It is completely legal to use { "class":"foo" } in JSON (and IE)